# How to reference data variable from another data variable in Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js

I have this in vue data:

```
data() {
    return {

      names: [],
      length: names.length,
}
```

But this does not work as RefereneError ( names is undefined ) is thrown. I used this.names but makes no difference.

Comment: `length` is obviously not a property *on its own*, it is **computed** from `names`. So what does that suggest to you?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to do something like this to make it work:

#1st way

```
data() {
    let defaultNames = [];
    return {
      names: defaultNames,
      length: defaultNames.length
    }
}
```

#2nd way — using computed data (the better way):

```
data() {
    return {
      names: [],
    }
},
computed: {
    length() {
        return this.names.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the specific example information the 1st way is probably not ideal (is length even reactive there? i haven't checked). But there are other scenarios where the 1st way is perfectly valid and maybe preferable (like if you're directly manipulating data based on other data at the time of initialization)

Comment: I'm curious about the binding as well. In the first approach it seems like `names` and `length` are decoupled. In the second approach it seems like `length` would be bound to `names`. But what about vice versa? Is `length` read only in the second approach?

Comment: Hi sfmillier940, yes indeed in the second approach `length` is read only (you cannot directly set a computed value because it's bind to a `data` variable)

Comment: The 1st, in my case (I have a const instead of a let) it is perfect! Thanks.

Comment: For me 1st way was useful, as I don't need the property to be reactive, i just need to initialize a selected_item based on an items_array. Thanks