# How to render variables inside another variable in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Does Vue can render variables inside another variable, and if not how can I reach this?

---

```
data() {
  return {
    SQL: {
      columns: ["id", "status", "post"],
      table: "users",
      limit: 10,
      query: "SELECT {{columns}} FROM {{table}} WHERE 1 LIMIT {{limit}}"
    }
  }
},
computed: {
  makeSQL: {
    return this.SQL.query; // should return "SELECT id, status, post FROM users WHERE 1 LIMIT 10"
  }
},
```

---

Comment: You can check this post it is explained:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614837/how-to-reference-data-variable-from-another-data-variable-in-vue-2

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
data() {
  return {
    SQL: {
      columns: ["id", "status", "post"],
      table: "users",
      limit: 10,
      get query() {
         return `SELECT ${this.columns.join(',')} FROM ${this.table} WHERE 1 LIMIT ${this.limit}`
      }
    }
  }
},
computed: {
  makeSQL: {
    return this.SQL.query; // should return "SELECT id, status, post FROM users WHERE 1 LIMIT 10"
  }
},
```

PS: this is more of a javascript feature to generate a value based out of values of other keys in the object. <s>Not sure if Vue has something specific to offer on this regard.</s>

You could use the computed property makeSQL to return `SELECT ${this.columns.join(',')} FROM ${this.table} WHERE 1 LIMIT ${this.limit}` which should give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use computed variables for this. Move your query variable to a computed variable like so

```
computed: {
    query() {
        return 'SELECT ' + this.SQL.columns.join(',') + 'FROM ' + this.SQL.table + ' WHERE 1 LIMIT ' + this.SQL.limit;
    },
    makeSQL() {
        return this.query;
    }
}
```